# File Not found - very basic web dev help

Tags: apache

I have not done any web dev before.  I got my Apache server running on mac OS X, and set up a virtual host at /Users/dan/webapps.  So, when I go to http://localhost/ in my browser, my index.html in the webapps folder shows up, as expected.

I then created Users/dan/webapps/temp/ folder, and put a flash app in there, let's call it "test.html", along with the required "test.swf".  I restart the server. However, when i put http://localhost/temp into my browser, I get File Not Found.  How do I make the browser able to go to that directory, and when it goes there, have it start test.html.  I am using Safari. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should type: http://localhost/temp/test.html
a full path to your page,

Or you can change the name of your page from test.html to index.html and it would be loaded when you enter http://localhost/temp/, since the default DirectoryIndex is index.htm or index.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file in `Users/dan/webapps/temp/`, and add the line:

```
DirectoryIndex test.html
```

This will make apache look for `test.html` when someone accesses the *directory*. Make sure permissions/ownership allows your webserver to read this file.